# HTTP/S requests not getting through suddenly using axios - Works fine on browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, https, axios

There is a strange issue that I have been facing for a few hours. Suddenly all https/http requests are not getting through from axios. But it just works fine on browser. For example, the following snippet:

```
axios({
   url: "https://subdomain.mydomain.com/path/1/1/3",
   method: "post",
   data: {
      grade: "4"
   }
}).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

This throws `UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE`. It started happening suddenly. Similarly for a simple GET request. It works fine on browser if I load it. For example, consider a sample GET request `https://qa-wms.reverieinc.com/version`. If you would hit this in browser everything looks okay, the SSL certificate and everything.

But if I try using axios:

```
axios({
  url: "https://qa-wms.reverieinc.com/version",
  method: "get"
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

throws an error saying `UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE`.

[image]

I have been struggling with this for some time now. What could be the issue here? It worked absolutely some hours back.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure axios to use a custom agent and set rejectUnauthorized to false for that agent:

```
// At request level
const agent = new https.Agent({  
  rejectUnauthorized: false
});
axios.get('https://qa-wms.reverieinc.com/version', { httpsAgent: agent });
```

**Second Method:**

The other secure way is that you have to include the Intermediate certificate in your server.

Comment: Please attach caveats to advice about disabling TLS features. This leaves the connection open to MITM attacks as the certificate won't be verified against a CA. Don't blindly use this in a production system.

Comment: yes, correct. this is only recommended for the development. the second approach is recommended